# ORACLE Is possible to execute a store procedure from a trigger?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

ORACLE Is it possible to execute a store procedure from a trigger?

Hi, I'm trying to execute a store procedure from a trigger.
I've tested the store procedure and it works fine:

```
EXECUTE ESCRIBE_INVENTARIO;
```

Then I create the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REPORTUSER.VENTA_ECOMMERCE 
AFTER UPDATE ON  INVOICE FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
ESCRIBE_INVENTARIO;
END;
/
```

But when I compile it I got this error:

Trigger VENTA_ECOMMERCE compilado

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
2/1       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/1       PLS-00201: identifier 'ESCRIBE_INVENTARIO' must be declared
Errores: comprobar log de compilador
```

I don't know how to declare the store procedure.

this is the header for the store procedure, there is no procedure body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ESCRIBE_INVENTARIO
IS
    EXISTE NUMBER; -- CREACIÓN DE LA VARIABLE QUE VERIFICA SI YA SE GENERO EL INVENTARIO DIARIO

    BEGIN

    SELECT (SELECT COUNT(BANDERA_CONTROL) FROM REPORTUSER.CONTROL_INVENTARIO_V WHERE TRUNC(FECHA) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND BANDERA_CONTROL = 1) INTO EXISTE FROM DUAL;

        IF EXISTE = 0 THEN
```

...

Comment: Is the procedure `ESCRIBE_INVENTARIO` is created in the schema: `REPORTUSER`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is definitely possible to execute a procedure from the trigger.

The only reason I could imagine here is the REPORTUSER doesn't have access to the procedure.

Try to grant execute priviledge to the reportuser

```
grant execute on ESCRIBE_INVENTARIO to REPORTUSER;
```

and put the owner name before procedure name in the trigger code, like

```
begin
  owner.escrive_inventario;
end;
```

The owner's name could be obtained from dba_objects

```
select owner, object_name from dba_objects where object_name = 'ESCRIBE_INVENTARIO';
```